# Можно ли виджет из tkinter открыть в PySide (PyQt)?

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, pyqt, pyside

Нужен кастомный сложный виджет, который нашёлся в **`tkinter`**.
Моё приложение сделано в **`PySide`** (`PyQt`).

Можно ли первый открыть в виджете из `PySide`?

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text="Python rocks!")
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
label1= QLabel("insert tkinter's widget below")
layout.addWidget(label1) #QPushButton('Top'))
label2 = QLabel('')
layout.addWidget(label2) #QPushButton('Bottom'))
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совместное использование двух наборов инструментов GUI редко возможно,
практически сложно, крайне не рекомендуется и почти всегда ненужно,
и совершенно неправильно.

Либо используйте Tk, либо Qt.

Чисто для визуализации, а не для практического применения:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font


class Widget2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.w2 = Tk()
        self.w2.geometry('200x150')
            
        self.button1 = Button(self.w2, text = "Button", 
            font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Calibri", size = 9), 
            cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
        self.button1.place(x = 60, y = 20, width = 90, height = 22)


class Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")
        self.resize(500, 450)

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Button", self)
        self.button1.setGeometry(9, 214, 482, 22)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.go_tkinter)

    def go_tkinter(self):
        widget2 = Widget2()
        widget2.w2.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Widget1()
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]